# How to use Order id in square-connect payment gateway in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, paypal, payment-gateway, square-connect

> I use this code, this is working done payment when I remove OrderId: "21071" this, but I want to use OrderId: "21071" this is "21071" my website order id that customer place order from my website.

```
ChargeRequest body = new ChargeRequest(AmountMoney: amount, IdempotencyKey: uuid, CardNonce: nonce, BillingAddress: address, ShippingAddress: address, BuyerEmailAddress: txtEmail.Text, ReferenceId: "Booking #:" + bookingid, Note: bookingid, OrderId: "21071");

    ChargeResponse response = transactionsApi.Charge(LocationId, body);
```

> I face this error

```
Error calling Charge: {"errors":[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"NOT_FOUND","detail":"Resource not found.","field":"order_id"}]}
```

> My error occurs when I use Orderid without Orderid it works fine, but I want to use Orderid

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using your *own* Order ID there, instead of creating an Order using the Orders API first, and then referencing that Order ID in your Transaction.

You can find an example of how to use the Square Orders API here: https://developer.squareup.com/docs/orders-api/cookbook/link-orders-and-catalog-item